# How to Compare two BigInteger variables as unsigned?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have two BigInteger variables whose values are initialized from 8 byte arrays:

```
maxOne: ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
midOne: 8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000
```

I would like to use a BigInteger comparison method that would return that maxOne is greater than midOne.

However, I keep getting the opposite. i.e.  midOne is greater than maxOne.

Internally, I could see that they are stored as:

maxOne:

```
mag[0]: 1
signum: -1
```

midOne

```
mag[0]: 7FFF7FFF
mag[1]: 7FFF7FFF
mag[2]: 7FFF7FFF
mag[3]: 7FFF8000
signum: -1
```

I would think a "larger absolute" value is lesser than a "smaller absolute" value when both have signum=-1 (e.g. -3 is lesser than -1).

But for some reason, `maxOne.compareTo(midOne)` returns -1.

When examining their `BigInteger.doubleValue()`, I see that

```
maxOne = -1.0
midOne = -1.7013858727242528 E38
```

Even if compareTo() were to use the doubleValue() to do the compare, maxOne > midOne.

So, why is the comparison returning the opposite?

Either way, I am interested comparing them as two **unsigned integers**. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS `abs()` only negates the `signum`, so compareTo() keeps returning midOne as greater than maxOne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to put a zero byte at the most significant place. So that no sign bit can creep in when creating the BigInteger.

Comment: That is a great idea. Works like a charm.